# In a custom directive, how can I perform logic before generating the template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, directive

I would like to write a custom directive that takes an array of strings, and renders it into a table like so:

```
'string1'  | 'string2'  | 'string3'  | 'string4'
'string5'  | 'string6'  | 'string7'  | 'string8'
'string9'  | 'string10' | 'string11' | 'string12'
```

It should be used like so:

```
<div class="my-directive" values="values" rowsize="4"></div>
```

I think the appropriate strategy to acheive this, would be to first split `values` into arrays of size `rowsize`. Then, render an `ng-repeat` with an inner `ng-repeat`. So the outputted DOM of the directive would look something like so:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="part in parts">
        <td ng-repeat="value in part">
            {{value}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This means inside the directive I need to *first do some logic* (split the array into smaller arrays), *and then use `ng-repeat`* as demonstrated above.

This directive could also be written using manual DOM manipulaton, but I want to do things 'the Angular' way :)

So, the question is: in a custom directive, how can I first do some logic (usually done in the `link` function), and then generate a template (usually placed in the `template` attribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://plnkr.co/edit/UYMQtMuZeJRcSQynHUGW?p=info

Basically, we need to dynamically create row objects that contain an array of items. And we only want to add to this array of items if we haven't reached the maximum number of allowable columns, as specified by whatever was passed into the directive via `maxColumns`:

As you'll see via the plunker you are able to modify the `max-columns` attribute in the HTML, and the directive should paint appropriately:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [
    'string1','string2','string3','string4','string5','string6',
    'string7','string8','string9','string10','string11','string12'
  ];
});

app.directive('myTable', function() {

  var templateHtml = 
      '<table border="1">' +
          '<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">' + 
              '<td ng-repeat="item in row.items">{{item}}</td>' +
          '</tr>' + 
      '</table>';

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: templateHtml,
    scope: {
      values: '=',
      maxColumns: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.rows = [];
        scope.rows.push(_getNewRow())

        function _getNewRow() {
          return { items: [] };
        }

        _.each(scope.values, function(value) {
            currentRow = _.last(scope.rows);
            if (currentRow.items.length < scope.maxColumns) {
               currentRow.items.push(value);
            } else {
               currentRow = _getNewRow();
               currentRow.items.push(value);
               scope.rows.push(currentRow);
            }
        });

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I see. I thought about doing that; including both a `template` and a `link`. But then I tested this approach, and it seemed the `link` function *overrides* the `template`. However, is it so that the template is 'compiled' *after* the `link` function runs, thus allowing your suggestion to work?

Comment: As I understand it, the compilation phase is run just once per directive, and is a place where we can do one-time DOM manipulation before Angular clones it for each instance found on the page. However, the linking phase is executed once per instance of the directive - as a result, its a place where we get to attach specific data to the scope of the directive. And at this point, the template is attached to the scope, and we just need to populate our scope with data - once link is run, a digest cycle kicks off, and we see our data bound in the template.

Comment: What I mean is, `rows` is used in the template *before* the `link` function is run and puts it on the scope. So does this mean the template is 'compiled' (that is, 'translated' to 'real HTML') *after* the running of the `link` function? Because if the template was translated to actual DOM *before* the `link` is run, `scope.rows` would be `undefined`.

Comment: This will show the exact order of the operations within a directive, pop open the console when running. Compilation is run before link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3hxqWviLdbXdyF88z5t You'll note that the compile function (`pre`) runs before everything, but then the 'post` runs last. This `post` in the `compile` function _is_ the `link` function we typically use. Again, linking is done after the DOM tree is established, we just link our data to the scope, which is already present. Moreover, since `post` compile / `link` is run last, we can access parent scopes from here as well.